# How can I require at least 1 occurrence of an element in the XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I require the "Address" element?

If I perform an XSD validation on a document with no "Address" it passes, but I would like it to fail.

Is this possible?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSD
see the example xsd. it hiding my xsd sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Recipient" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="House" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Town" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="County" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="PostCode" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Country">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="FR" />
              <xs:enumeration value="DE" />
              <xs:enumeration value="ES" />
              <xs:enumeration value="UK" />
              <xs:enumeration value="US" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: example XML and schema, please

Comment: There seem to be a problem when validating an Excel xml output to an XSD, it always seems to pass. I'm going to post a new revised question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set `minOccurs="1"` in its definition.

Example taken from [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_example.asp):

```
<xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The `note` element must appear at least once under `item`, but the others don't have to appear.

Comment: Address is your root element. It's always required otherwise there is no XML document. I don't understand your question.

Comment: The XSD does not require it, if for some reason something else is there it still validates.

Comment: example please?  I don't get what you're saying.  The answer to the original question is "minOccurs='1'".  Now you have another question but it's not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Default value for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` is 1, so the problem is somewhere else...